# trying to install tqdm, but it says it is already installed?

Tags: python-3.x, pip, anaconda, conda, tqdm

So I am trying to run the following command:

```
conda install nomkl
```

which throws the following error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
      File "d:\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\conda\exceptions.py", line 1079, in __call__
        return func(*args, **kwargs)
      File "d:\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\conda\cli\main.py", line 84, in _main
        exit_code = do_call(args, p)
      File "d:\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\conda\cli\conda_argparse.py", line 83, in do_call
        return getattr(module, func_name)(args, parser)
      File "d:\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\conda\cli\main_install.py", line 20, in execute
        install(args, parser, 'install')
      File "d:\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\conda\cli\install.py", line 116, in install
        if context.use_only_tar_bz2:
      File "d:\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\conda\base\context.py", line 714, in use_only_tar_bz2
        import conda_package_handling.api
      File "d:\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\conda_package_handling\api.py", line 7, in <module>
        import tqdm as _tqdm
    ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'tqdm'

`$ D:\anaconda3\Scripts\conda-script.py install nomkl`

  environment variables:
                 CIO_TEST=<not set>
        CONDA_DEFAULT_ENV=FO2
                CONDA_EXE=D:\anaconda3\condabin\..\Scripts\conda.exe
               CONDA_EXES="D:\anaconda3\condabin\..\Scripts\conda.exe"
             CONDA_PREFIX=D:\anaconda3\envs\FO2
           CONDA_PREFIX_1=D:\anaconda3
    CONDA_PROMPT_MODIFIER=(FO2)
         CONDA_PYTHON_EXE=D:\anaconda3\python.exe
               CONDA_ROOT=D:\anaconda3
              CONDA_SHLVL=2
           CURL_CA_BUNDLE=<not set>
                 HOMEPATH=\Users\Nick's AMD
                     PATH=D:\anaconda3;D:\anaconda3\Library\mingw-w64\bin;D:\anaconda3\Library\u
                          sr\bin;D:\anaconda3\Library\bin;D:\anaconda3\Scripts;D:\anaconda3\bin;
                          D:\anaconda3\envs\FO2;D:\anaconda3\envs\FO2\Library\mingw-w64\bin;D:\a
                          naconda3\envs\FO2\Library\usr\bin;D:\anaconda3\envs\FO2\Library\bin;D:
                          \anaconda3\envs\FO2\Scripts;D:\anaconda3\envs\FO2\bin;D:\anaconda3\con
                          dabin;C:\Program Files (x86)\NVIDIA
                          Corporation\PhysX\Common;C:\Program Files (x86)\Common Files\Oracle\Ja
                          va\javapath;C:\Windows\system32;C:\Windows;C:\Windows\System32\Wbem;C:
                          \Windows\System32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0;C:\Windows\System32\OpenSSH;C
                          :\Program Files\Intel\WiFi\bin;C:\Program Files\Common
                          Files\Intel\WirelessCommon;C:\Program Files\nodejs;C:\ProgramData\choc
                          olatey\bin;C:\WINDOWS\system32;C:\WINDOWS;C:\WINDOWS\System32\Wbem;C:\
                          WINDOWS\System32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0;C:\WINDOWS\System32\OpenSSH;C:
                          \Program Files\NVIDIA Corporation\NVIDIA NvDLISR;C:\Program Files
                          (x86)\Windows Kits\8.1\Windows Performance Toolkit;C:\Program
                          Files\Microsoft SQL Server\Client SDK\ODBC\110\Tools\Binn;C:\Program
                          Files (x86)\Microsoft SQL Server\120\Tools\Binn;C:\Program
                          Files\Microsoft SQL Server\120\Tools\Binn;C:\Program Files\Microsoft
                          SQL Server\120\DTS\Binn;C:\Program Files\Git\cmd;D:\anaconda3;D:\anaco
                          nda3\Library\mingw-w64\bin;D:\anaconda3\Library\usr\bin;D:\anaconda3\L
                          ibrary\bin;D:\anaconda3\Scripts;C:\Users\Nick's
                          AMD\AppData\Local\Microsoft\WindowsApps;C:\Program
                          Files\Intel\WiFi\bin;C:\Program Files\Common
                          Files\Intel\WirelessCommon;C:\Users\Nick's
                          AMD\AppData\Roaming\npm;C:\Users\Nick's
                          AMD\AppData\Local\Programs\Microsoft VS Code\bin;C:\Users\Nick's
                          AMD\AppData\Local\atom\bin;C:\Users\Nick's
                          AMD\AppData\Local\Microsoft\WindowsApps;C:\Users\Nick's
                          AMD\AppData\Local\hyper\app-3.0.2\resources\bin
             PSMODULEPATH=C:\Program Files\WindowsPowerShell\Modules;C:\WINDOWS\system32\Windows
                          PowerShell\v1.0\Modules;C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft SQL
                          Server\120\Tools\PowerShell\Modules\
       REQUESTS_CA_BUNDLE=<not set>
            SSL_CERT_FILE=<not set>

     active environment : FO2
    active env location : D:\anaconda3\envs\FO2
            shell level : 2
       user config file : C:\Users\Nick's AMD\.condarc
 populated config files : C:\Users\Nick's AMD\.condarc
          conda version : 4.9.2
    conda-build version : 3.20.5
         python version : 3.8.5.final.0
       virtual packages : __cuda=11.2=0
                          __win=0=0
                          __archspec=1=x86_64
       base environment : D:\anaconda3  (writable)
           channel URLs : https://repo.anaconda.com/pkgs/main/win-64
                          https://repo.anaconda.com/pkgs/main/noarch
                          https://repo.anaconda.com/pkgs/r/win-64
                          https://repo.anaconda.com/pkgs/r/noarch
                          https://repo.anaconda.com/pkgs/msys2/win-64
                          https://repo.anaconda.com/pkgs/msys2/noarch
          package cache : D:\anaconda3\pkgs
                          C:\Users\Nick's AMD\.conda\pkgs
                          C:\Users\Nick's AMD\AppData\Local\conda\conda\pkgs
       envs directories : D:\anaconda3\envs
                          C:\Users\Nick's AMD\.conda\envs
                          C:\Users\Nick's AMD\AppData\Local\conda\conda\envs
               platform : win-64
             user-agent : conda/4.9.2 requests/2.24.0 CPython/3.8.5 Windows/10 Windows/10.0.18362
          administrator : False
             netrc file : None
           offline mode : False


An unexpected error has occurred. Conda has prepared the above report.
```

This leads me to believe that I need to install tqdm to fix the error. When I run

```
pip install tqdm
```

it says

```
Requirement already satisfied: tqdm in d:\anaconda3\envs\fo2\lib\site-packages (4.24.0)
```

What am I doing wrong? How can I install tqdm if it is already installed? I am wondering if it is an issue with conda. It seems like when I try to install other things with conda it gives me the same error.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looks like you're trying to install `tqdm` within `fo2` virtualenv meanwhile conda itself runs outside of it. Try to install `tqdm` globally, from the separate shell with no envs activated. Or even just update the `conda` using global `pip` :)

Answer (score 0):

Maybe specifying the pip version helps.

Like: `pip3 install tqdm` or `pip3.6 install tqdm`

However, if you are using conda environment as default, install the package via conda terminal or anaconda package installer interface.